# Grouping and Column Filtering on jQuery DataTable at different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables with Grouping and Filtering on data. But both can't work together. Only one can work.

```
oTable = $('#schedule').dataTable({
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bJQueryUI': true,
    'processing': true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
       { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": ["no-sort"] }
    ]
}).columnFilter({
   sPlaceHolder:"head:before"
}).rowGrouping({
    sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",
    bExpandableGrouping: true,
    bExpandSingleGroup: false,
    iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
    asExpandedGroups: ['Pending Action', 'In Operation']
});
```

Please give me advice on how to work with both and I want to add the filter field in different `div`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt work because you are using chaining. You are accidently trying to initialise rowGrouping on whatever `columnFilter()` returns :

```
dataTable().columnFilter().rowGrouping()
            < dataTable    < columnFilter
```

Use another approach to initialise the plugins, for example in the `initComplete` callback (`fnInitComplete` if you are using 1.9.x) :

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
   initComplete : function() {
      this.columnFilter();
      this.rowGrouping({
          bExpandableGrouping: true,
          asExpandedGroups: ["Other Browsers", "Trident"],
          fnOnGrouped: function() { alert('Rows are regrouped!'); }
      });
   }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y2s2b0an/**